# Java's HttpURLConnection doesn't support REPORT/PROPFIND - what shall I do?

Tags: java, caldav

HttpURLConnection does only support things like GET, POST and HEAD - but no REPORT/PROPFIND. I'm going to implement a CalDAV-Client but without theese operations (if I want to use them I get a ProtocolException) I have to write/deliver a complete and huge HTTP library with auth and so on.

"Overkill".

How do I send requests with PROPFIND and REPORT?

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem on WebDav for PROPFIND method.

Solved the problem by implementing this solution:
https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-639

```
    try {
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(method);
        } catch (final ProtocolException pe) {
            try {
                final Class<?> httpURLConnectionClass = httpURLConnection
                        .getClass();
                final Class<?> parentClass = httpURLConnectionClass
                        .getSuperclass();
                final Field methodField;
                // If the implementation class is an HTTPS URL Connection, we
                // need to go up one level higher in the heirarchy to modify the
                // 'method' field.
                if (parentClass == HttpsURLConnection.class) {
                    methodField = parentClass.getSuperclass().getDeclaredField(
                            "method");
                } else {
                    methodField = parentClass.getDeclaredField("method");
                }
                methodField.setAccessible(true);
                methodField.set(httpURLConnection, method);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);

            }
     }
```

Comment: Good answer! However, in my case, the httpURLConnection have a delegate and the answer does not work. Therefore I extract the delegate field of httpURLConnection object by reflexion. The delegate field is also the (sub sub) sub class of HttpURLConnection. I apply your procedure for this delegate connection by methodField = parentClass.getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("method");. This works well. thanks!

Comment: I tried the above solution, and got erro as "http method not allowed". Could you please give any pointer on this. I also see httpURLConnection has a delegate, but when I tried the commented solution, i get noSuchMethod error.

Comment: @KNaito could you please help me to fix this issue, I'm using JDK 1.7 and directly using HttpUrlConnection

Comment: I use the following codes,
```
if (parentClass == HttpsURLConnection.class) {
                    methodField = parentClass.getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("method");
                } else if (parentClass == HttpURLConnection.class) {
                    methodField = parentClass.getDeclaredField("method");
                } else {
                    methodField = parentClass.getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("method");
                }
                methodField.setAccessible(true);
                methodField.set(httpURLConnection, method);
``` @Dhamayanthi

Comment: The reason that you get noSuchMethod error is that your class (parentClass) is not the HttpsURLConnection.class nor HttpURLConnection.class but the descendant class. Therefore you should go back to the HttpURLConnectionc.class by using getSuperclass() method.

Comment: my conn object also has delegate (sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection) and i'm trying to extract delegate as you mentioned in your first comment, but not knowing how to set method on that delegate. I guess I'm doing something wrong when i'm extracting delete and if (parentClass == HttpsURLConnection.class) is true for me. Could you please share your complete method that does this as given in the answer. btw, I'm trying to implement PATCH method and when i tried as per the answer i get "HttpMethodNotFound" @KNaito

Comment: Sorry, here is no space for the complete code. I think there are two thing. One is how to get `parentClass`. my code is ```
Field delegateField;
delegateField = connection.getClass().getDeclaredField("delegate");
delegateField.setAccessible(true);
HttpURLConnection delegateConnection = (HttpURLConnection) delegateField.get(connection);
final Class<?> httpURLConnectionClass = delegateConnection.getClass();
final Class<?> parentClass = httpURLConnectionClass.getSuperclass();
``` @Dhamayanthi

Comment: The other thing is that the HttpsURLConnection / HttpsURLConnection in if statement are javax.net.ssl.Https.URLConnection / java.net.HttpURLConnection. Remark that the java.net.HttpURLConnection class has a protected `method` field.

Comment: Thank you @KNaito, Your last hint helped me to identify the issue, it was the issue with java.net.HttpURLConnection

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably want to look for a WebDAV libary, not an HTTP library, for this one.

Maybe take a look at [Apache Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/1.3/org/apache/jackrabbit/webdav/DavServletRequest.html).

Comment: +1 for the link to Jackrabbit, although the link you've sent is for the server side. This might be more directly relevant: http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/1.3/org/apache/jackrabbit/webdav/client/methods/package-summary.html

Comment: Broken links here

Answer (score 3):

Either you can use https://github.com/square/okhttp

**Sample Code**

```
    // using OkHttp
    public class PropFindExample {        
    private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String run(String url) throws IOException {
        String credential = Credentials.basic(userName, password);
        // body
        String body = "<d:propfind xmlns:d=\"DAV:\" xmlns:cs=\"http://calendarserver.org/ns/\">\n" +
                "  <d:prop>\n" +
                "     <d:displayname />\n" +
                "     <d:getetag />\n" +
                "  </d:prop>\n" +
                "</d:propfind>";
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .method("PROPFIND", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(body), body))
                .header("DEPTH", "1")
                .header("Authorization", credential)
                .header("Content-Type", "text/xml")
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }
 }
```

Or play with Sockets

**Sample Code**

```
String host = "example.com";
int port = 443;
String path = "/placeholder";
String userName = "username";
String password = "password";

SSLSocketFactory ssf = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
Socket socket = ssf.createSocket(host, port);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())));

// xml data to be sent in body
String xmlData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?> <d:propfind xmlns:d=\"DAV:\" xmlns:cs=\"http://calendarserver.org/ns/\"> <d:prop> <d:displayname /> <d:getetag /> </d:prop> </d:propfind>";
// append headers
out.println("PROPFIND path HTTP/1.1");
out.println("Host: "+host);
String userCredentials = username+":"+password;
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(userCredentials.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
String authorization = "Authorization: " + basicAuth;
out.println(authorization.trim());
out.println("Content-Length: "+ xmlData.length());
out.println("Content-Type: text/xml");
out.println("Depth: 1");
out.println();
// append body
out.println(xmlData);
out.flush();

// get response
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;

System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
System.out.println("---------------Printing response--------------------------");
System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(inputLine);
}

in.close();
```

Comment: Please don't [copy/paste](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35490228/189134) the same answer to multiple questions. Instead customize the answer to the individual questions and explain how they solve that particular issue.

Comment: Sure! Thanks for your message!

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use another HTTP library, such as [Apache HTTP client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/) and extend its [`HttpRequestBase`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpRequestBase.html) (see `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` for example).

Alternatively, you could use a WebDAV client library directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection conn, String method) throws Throwable {
    try {
        conn.setRequestMethod(method);
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Class<?> c = conn.getClass();
        Field methodField = null;
        Field delegateField = null;
        try {
            delegateField = c.getDeclaredField("delegate");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException nsfe) {

        }
        while (c != null && methodField == null) {
            try {
                methodField = c.getDeclaredField("method");
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException nsfe) {

            }
            if (methodField == null) {
                c = c.getSuperclass();
            }
        }
        if (methodField != null) {
            methodField.setAccessible(true);
            methodField.set(conn, method);
        }

        if (delegateField != null) {
            delegateField.setAccessible(true);
            HttpURLConnection delegate = (HttpURLConnection) delegateField.get(conn);
            setRequestMethod(delegate, method);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Caldav4j](http://code.google.com/p/caldav4j)

It supports:

- easy generation of report requests
- based on httpclient 3.0
- android app
- currently migrating to jackrabbit

Answer (score 0):

"method PROPFIND must not have a request body. this exception is occured when execute this code."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

"method PROPFIND must not have a request body. this exception is occured when executing this code  above sample code 3  .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).