# Loading CSV into Power Query from Spring Boot site with basic authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication, powerquery

I want to implement site which allows user to generate and download CSV file. 
The page is secured by Spring Security with basic authentication:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authentication)
            throws Exception
    {
        authentication.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin"))
                .authorities("ROLE_USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

I have to enable loading the file directly into Excel via Power Query by entering URL as filename:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaTjL.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K7iz.png)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOlrE.png)

After entering URL and providing credentials nothing happens and Excel still asks for them. Furthermore, compiler gives info about exception being thrown:

```
    2019-07-12 14:05:15.610 ERROR 15152 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/worklogs] due to exception [The request was rejected because the HTTP method "PROPFIND" was not included within the whitelist [HEAD, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT]]

org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the HTTP method "PROPFIND" was not included within the whitelist [HEAD, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT]
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.rejectForbiddenHttpMethod(StrictHttpFirewall.java:316) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(StrictHttpFirewall.java:292) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:194) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:128) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Below I put all the code responsible for generating and downloading CSV file:

```java
@GetMapping("/worklogs")
    public String passForm(@RequestParam Map<String,String> allRequestParams, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws IOException, JSONException {

        StringBuilder stringParams = new StringBuilder("?");
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : allRequestParams.entrySet()){
            stringParams.append(entry.getKey()).append("=").append(entry.getValue()).append("&");
        }

        // if true, generate and download .csv file, else - display table
        if(Objects.equals("on", request.getParameter("csv"))){
            return "redirect:/worklogs/csv" + stringParams;
        }
        return showAsTable(model, request, stringParams.toString());
    }
```

```java
@GetMapping("/csv")
public void showAsCsv(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, JSONException {

    currentLogs = getFilteredWorklogs(request);

    Collections.sort(currentLogs);

        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder("updated;username;email;comment;hours;issue_id;issue_url" + "\n");

        for (Worklog w : currentLogs) {
            content
                    .append("\"")
                    .append(w.getUpdated())
                    .append("\";\"")
                    .append(w.getUpdateAuthor().getName())
                    .append("\";\"")
                    .append(w.getUpdateAuthor().getEmailAddress())
                    .append("\";\"")
                    .append(w.getComment())
                    .append("\";\"")
                    .append(w.getHoursSpent())
                    .append("\";\"")
                    .append(w.getIssueKey())
                    .append("\";\"")
                    .append(w.getIssueUrl())
                    .append("\"\n");
        }
        currentLogs = null;

        response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "worklogs.csv");
        response.getWriter().print(content);
}
```

```java
public List<Worklog> getFilteredWorklogs(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, JSONException {

        String since = request.getParameter("since");
        String days = request.getParameter("days");
        String beginString = request.getParameter("begin");
        String endString = request.getParameter("end");
        String projectName = request.getParameter("project");
        String userName = request.getParameter("user");

        LocalDate begin, end;
        LocalDate[] dates = convertStringInterval(since, days, beginString, endString);

        // true if an date input error occured
        if (Objects.isNull(dates)){
            return null;
        }

        begin = dates[0];
        end = dates[1];

        // getting all worklogs updated between begin and end dates
        List<Long> updatedIds = getIdsUpdatedBetween(begin, end);

        if(Objects.isNull(updatedIds)){
            return null;
        }

        // splitting list of updated worklogs into lists containing 1000 worklogs (Jira REST API limit)
        List<List<Long>> groupedUpdatedIds = new ArrayList<>();
        int groupBegin = 0, groupEnd = 999;

        // if true, grouping is needed
        if(updatedIds.size() > 1000){
            do{
                groupedUpdatedIds.add(updatedIds.subList(groupBegin, groupEnd));
                groupBegin = groupEnd + 1;
                if(groupEnd + 1000 < updatedIds.size()){
                    groupEnd += 1000;
                } else groupEnd = updatedIds.size() - 1;
            } while (groupEnd < updatedIds.size() - 1);
        } else groupedUpdatedIds.add(updatedIds);

        List<Worklog> filteredLogs = new ArrayList<>();

        for(List<Long> list : groupedUpdatedIds){
            String body = parseIdsToJSON(list);
            filteredLogs.addAll(extractWorklog(body, prefix + "/rest/api/2/worklog/list"));
        }

        List<Issue> issues = issueController.getIssuesFromIdList(filteredLogs);

        for (Worklog filteredLog : filteredLogs) {
            for (Issue is : issues) {
                if (Objects.equals(is.getId(), filteredLog.getIssueId())) {
                    filteredLog.setIssueKey(is.getKey());
                    filteredLog.setIssueUrl(is.getSelf());
                    filteredLog.setProjectName(is.getProjectName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return filteredLogs;
    }
```

```java
public LocalDate[] convertStringInterval(String since, String days, String beginString, String endString){

        LocalDate[] interval = new LocalDate[2];

        if(Objects.isNull(filters)){
            filters = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        switch(since){
            case "week":{
                interval[0] = LocalDate.now().minusWeeks(1);
                interval[1] = LocalDate.now();
                filters.add("since last week");
                break;
            }
            case "month":{
                interval[0] = LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1);
                interval[1] = LocalDate.now();
                filters.add("since last month");
                break;
            }
            case "year":{
                interval[0] = LocalDate.now().minusYears(1);
                interval[1] = LocalDate.now();
                filters.add("since last year");
                break;
            }
            case "days":{
                if(!Objects.equals("", days)){
                    long longDays = Long.parseLong(days);
                    if(longDays > 0){
                        interval[0] = LocalDate.now().minusDays(longDays);
                        interval[1] = LocalDate.now();
                        filters.add("since last " + longDays + " days");
                    } else {
                        prompt.addMessage("wrongdays");
                        return null;
                    }
                } else {
                    prompt.addMessage("nodays");
                    return null;
                }
                break;
            }
            case "interval":{
                if(!Objects.equals("", beginString) && !Objects.equals("", endString)){
                    interval[0] = LocalDate.parse(beginString);
                    interval[1] = LocalDate.parse(endString);
                    filters.add("between " + beginString + " and " + endString);
                } else {
                    prompt.addMessage("nointerval");
                    return null;
                }
                break;
            }
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + since);
        }
        return interval;
    }
```

```java
private List<Long> getIdsUpdatedBetween(LocalDate begin, LocalDate end){

        // getting worklogs updated since 'begin' to present
        String uri = prefix + "/rest/api/2/worklog/updated?since=" + DateConverter.localDateToEpoch(begin);
        boolean lastPage;

        List<Long> filteredWorklogsIds = new ArrayList<>();

        try{
            String allWorklogsString;
            JSONObject obj;
            do{
                // parsing JSON object to String
                allWorklogsString = invokeGetMethod(hash, uri);

                if(Objects.isNull(allWorklogsString)){
                    prompt.addMessage("notloggedin");
                    return null;
                }

                obj = new JSONObject(Objects.requireNonNull(allWorklogsString));
                JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("values");

                long endAsLong = DateConverter.localDateToEpoch(end);

                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
                    long worklogId = Long.parseLong(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("worklogId"));
                    long updatedTime = Long.parseLong(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("updatedTime"));

                    // getting worklogs updated until end included
                    if(updatedTime <= endAsLong)
                        filteredWorklogsIds.add(worklogId);
                }

                lastPage = obj.getBoolean("lastPage");

                if(!lastPage)
                    uri = obj.getString("nextPage");

            } while(!lastPage);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return filteredWorklogsIds;
    }
```

```java
public List<Worklog> extractWorklog(String body, String url){

        MultiValueMap<String, String> multiValueMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        multiValueMap.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        multiValueMap.add("Authorization",  "Basic " + hash);
        multiValueMap.add("Accept", "application/json");

        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, multiValueMap);
        ResponseEntity<List<Worklog>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Worklog>>(){});

        return responseEntity.getBody();
    }
```

```java
public List<Issue> getIssuesFromIdList(List<Worklog> worklogs) throws JSONException, IOException {

        String issuesJqlQuery = "";
        List<Issue> issues = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 1; i <= worklogs.size(); i++){
            if(i%1000 == 1){
                issuesJqlQuery = "{\"jql\":\"";
            }

            issuesJqlQuery += "id=" + worklogs.get(i - 1).getIssueId();
            if(i%1000 != 0 && i < worklogs.size()){
                issuesJqlQuery += " OR ";
            } else {
                issuesJqlQuery += "\",\"maxResults\":1000}";
                String responseBody = extractIssues(issuesJqlQuery, prefix + "/search");

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(Objects.requireNonNull(responseBody));
                JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("issues");

                for(int j = 0; j < arr.length(); j++){

                    Long id = Long.parseLong(arr.getJSONObject(j).getString("id")); // getting issue id
                    String key = arr.getJSONObject(j).getString("key");             // getting issue key
                    String self = arr.getJSONObject(j).getString("self");           // getting issue url

                    // getting project username
                    String fields = arr.getJSONObject(j).getString("fields");
                    JSONObject projectObj = new JSONObject(fields);
                    String project = projectObj.getString("project");
                    JSONObject projectObj2 = new JSONObject(project);
                    String projectName = projectObj2.getString("name");

                    issues.add(new Issue(id, self, key, projectName));
                }
            }
        }
        return issues;
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I have created test controller with hardcoded CSV file content in the same project. It is loaded in Excel without problems, so I guess Spring Security configuration is ok.

```java
@Controller
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public void test(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "worklogs.csv");
        response.getWriter().print("updated;username;email;comment;hours;issue_id;issue_url\n" +
                "\"2019-07-04T08:37:21.958+0000\";\"test1\";\"test2\";\"\";\"2\";\"test3\";\"test4\"\n");
    }

}
```

Downloading file via browser or Postman works correctly and there aren't any problems with authorization. I have no idea, why authorization via Excel doesn't work, so I will be glad of any sugestions.

Answer (score 0):

"HTTP method PROPFIND" seems stange, as I wouldn't expect [WebDAV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459617/javas-httpurlconnection-doesnt-support-report-propfind-what-shall-i-do) to be used here -- if you change the URL hostname i.e. http://127.0.0.1/ or your local network IP address, does it work?

---

If that doesn't work, can you can install [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and compare successful web requests with the requests Microsoft.Mashup.Container is making?

Comment: Changing to IP address didn't work, guess that Fiddler is something similar to Wireshark which I've used to test it - without results. However - I've found what was causing the error:
**return "redirect:/worklogs/csv" + stringParams;**
Everything started working again when I removed this redirect. It seems that Excel had some difficulties with redirecting and couldn't handle my auth request correctly.